# LINQ query - search in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to write a method, that would search for matches in my database.

I have a combobox (in code as volba), which should tell in what column to look for matches and textbox (in code as retezec), which should be the searched term.

After debugging I've found out, that my query (dotaz) is always empty, even if I can see match with my own eyes.

Any suggestions?

```
DataDataContext db = new DataDataContext();
string volba = "a." + Vyber.Text;
string retezec = txt.Text.ToString();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id");
dt.Columns.Add("Nazev");
dt.Columns.Add("Popis");
dt.Columns.Add("Vyrobce");
dt.Columns.Add("Kusu");
dt.Columns.Add("Cena");
DataRow row = null;

var dotaz = from a in db.Zbozis
            where volba == retezec
            orderby a.Id
            select a;

foreach (var radek in dotaz)
{
    row = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(radek.Id, radek.Nazev, radek.Popis, radek.Vyrobce, radek.Kusu, radek.Cena);
}

zboziDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: check the generated SQL: ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)  dotaz ).ToTraceString();
I guess your problem is in the where clause

Comment: God - **why on earth** would take the result of a Linq query (which is a **nice, easily useable** .NET object) and turn it back into the crappy rows/columns representation of a `DataTable` ..... the **whole point** of using an ORM and Linq is that you **don't have to deal** with this untyped, insecure columns&rows format anymore, but instead you can use strongly-typed, type-safe .NET objects!

Comment: Because that was my first idea, how to display result in my data grid. If you have better one, then tell me. I'm new in C# and programming in general :)
So the problem is in volba, when I tried instead a.Vyrobce, it worked just fine, it just don't accept string. So new question, how to add variable volba in clause where, so the program could accept it?

Comment: Well the LINQ statement you have should give you an `IEnumerable<Zbozis>` - basically a fancy name for *a list of `Zbozis`* - why don't you just bind that list to the grid? Done! Absolutely no need for messy back-and-forth code here - just select your data using LINQ, and bind that result to a grid or a listview or whatever you're working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query doesn't do what you seem to expect. Basically this is what it's doing:

```
from a in db.Zbozis
where "a.Property" == "x"
orderby a.Id
select a;
```

and not

```
from a in db.Zbozis
where a.Property == "x"
orderby a.Id
select a;
```

Obviously the first query never returns anything because the predicate will never be true.

You need a tool or method that converts the *string* containing the property name and the parameter into an *expression*. [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) is often used for this. Also available through NuGet.

Comment: That's what I figured out also. So I downloaded Dynamic LINQ library, but so far, no luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to follow where you are going with this. I'd recommend grabbing [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and using that to test out your LINQ. It can connect to your database and execute LINQ.

As far as trying to match text in databases, LINQPad has a few samples that may help you get a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.